# how to raise exceptions in rspec for only some method calls

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some code that calls method `collect_money` at startup. Periodically, the method `collect_money` gets called asynchronously (event based, etc). I'd like to make collect_money raise an exception, e.g `NoMoney` on occasion, but not every time and definitely not the first time it gets executed. Is this possible? If not, what would be the alternative/recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to have deterministic tests, so that a test pass or always fail consistently.

You can stub this method and use a counter inside:

```
#assuming that obj has the method collect_money
allow(obj).to receive(:collect_money) do
  @counter ||= 0
  @counter += 1
  fail NoMoney if counter > 3 # raise exception in 4th call
  # ... return something useful in other cases
end
```